# nodejs 400 bad request err. when sending form data via XMLHttpRequest().send

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Im having trouble sending form data to my local NodeJS express server. I believe it has something to do with how I'm formatting my request. I am trying to register a new user account to a Postgresql database, using Passport as middleware, although I dont believe the code ever makes it that far.

Chrome DevTools Network Tab gives me additional info about the bad request
    {"status":"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"}

When a user hits 'Create Account', this code is fired off:

```
processForm(event) {
// prevent default action. in this case, action is the form submission event
event.preventDefault();

// create a string for an HTTP body message
const name = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.name);
const email = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.email);
const password = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.password);
const formData = `name=${name}&email=${email}&password=${password}`;

// create an AJAX request
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', '/auth/register');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // success

    // change the component-container state
    this.setState({
      errors: {}
    });

    // set a message
    localStorage.setItem('successMessage', xhr.response.message);
    this.setState({redirect: true});

  } else {
    // failure

    const errors = xhr.response.errors ? xhr.response.errors : {};
    errors.summary = xhr.response.message;

    this.setState({
      errors
    });
  }
});
xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Chrome DevTools flashes the 'xhr.send(formData)' as the first error in the stack.

This is the express handler code, but I don't think it ever makes it that far:

```
router.post('/register', authHelpers.loginRedirect, (req, res, next)  
=> {
return authHelpers.createUser(req, res)
.then((response) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (user) { handleResponse(res, 200, 'success'); }
    })(req, res, next);
})
.catch((err) => { handleResponse(res, 500, 'error'); });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent hours trying to troubleshoot it. That's like every stackoverflow post ever.

Comment: There is a standard object called [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) using the variable name `formData` for a string is quite confusing!

Comment: ahh! good to know. thank you